# How does one check a pool's delegation history?

Tags: cardano-cli, stake-pool, rewards, on-chain

How does one view addresses that were staking with a specific pool at a specific epoch boundary?

If there is any way to view a list of addresses that received staking rewards for a particular block, that could also do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need any kind of specific on chain information that isn't found on third party explorers like Cardanoscan, you'd have to use [db-sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/12.0.0/Readme.md) yourself. (It's what all the explorers use)

To quote directly from the db-sync github:

"
The purpose of Cardano DB Sync is to follow the Cardano chain and take information from the chain and an internally maintained copy of ledger state. Data is then extracted from the chain and inserted into a PostgreSQL database. SQL queries can then be written directly against the database schema or as queries embedded in any language with libraries for interacting with an SQL database.

Examples of what someone would be able to do via an SQL query against a Cardano DB Sync instance fully synced to a specific network is:

- Look up any block, transaction, address, stake pool etc on that network, usually by the hash that identifies that item or the index into another table.
- Look up the balance of any stake address for any Shelley or later epoch.
- Look up the amount of ADA delegated to each pool for any Shelley or later epoch.
  "

There are LOTS of examples in the [interesting sql queries](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/12.0.0/doc/interesting-queries.md)

Comment: Thanks a ton, especially for the examples link. This seems to be exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to setup `cardano-db-sync`, try [blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/) with the [/epochs/{number}/blocks/{pool_id}](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Epochs/paths/%7E1epochs%7E1%7Bnumber%7D%7E1blocks%7E1%7Bpool_id%7D/get) endpoint.

Comment: That's a great point about blockfrost. Checking it out has been on my TODO for several months.